# $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ action on $\mathbb{C} P^1$ induces action of Lie algebra by vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am in need of some assistance to solve problem 3.8 in Kirillov's *An Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*. Copied below:

> Let $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ act on $\mathbb{C} P^1$ in the usual way:
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} [x:y] = [ax+by:cx+dy].$$ 
>   This defines an action of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ 
>   by vector fields on $\mathbb{C} P^1$. Write explicitly
>   the vector fields corresponding to $h, e, f$ in terms of the
>   coordinate $t = x/y$ on the open cell $\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{C} P^1$.

I am aware that the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is equivalent to a map $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}P^1$, and further the pushforward $\rho_*$  defines the action of the Lie algebra. In terms of one-parameter subgroups, recalling $$ h = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix},$$ $\exp(sh)$ is a curve in the Lie group with tangent vector $h$ at $s=0$, and so the action of $h$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is defined to be  $$ \frac{d}{ds}\exp(sh)([x:y])|_{s=0} = \frac{d}{ds} [e^s x: e^{-s} y]|_{s=0}$$ at which point I'm a little confused.

Edit: I should also add that this is a homework assignment, so hints are strongly preferred over full solutions.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201290/lie-algebra-action-from-lie-group-action-coordinates?rq=1) question I asked a few years ago might be helpful, if you haven't looked at it yet.

Comment: I was not able to dig that up when I looked, thanks. I'll have to look it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have most of the solution. Now you just need to write the expression you got in means of the desired coordinate.

The complex coordinate on the set $U_y:=\{[x:y]|y\neq0\}$ is 
$$
\varphi:U_y\to\mathbb{C},\quad[x:y]\mapsto\frac{x}{y}.
$$
This means that the path whose velocity you are after is given by
$$
\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{C},\quad s\mapsto[e^sx:e^{-s}y]\mapsto e^{2s}\frac{x}{y}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so. One more dumb question: I assume one takes the derivative after rewriting? So then the answer is $2t$? I'm not sure how to interpret this as a vector field (no $\partial_x$ for example).

Comment: @DKS I would say $2t\partial_t$ (assuming $t$ is the name you chose for the complex coordinate).

Comment: This was enough of a hint to get me there. Thanks.